# What is "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable"?

Tags: python

I was working on web scraping, but the code is showing an error. How I can solve this?

I have installed all required packages related to BeautifulSoup.

```
import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = request.GET('https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki//Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

I expect the HTML of the website, but instead it is showing:

```
page = request.GET('https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki//Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)')
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: first off, what is `request`? Is that a typo for `requests` or a different package?

Comment: `request` is a a Flask sub package, you needs `requests`, with an s

Answer (score 3):

I think the code should be

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki//Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

At least this works on my side (Python 3.6).

As suggested in the comments `requests` is the Python canonical package for http calls, `request` is a sub-package inside `Flask` to access http call arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki//Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
page = soup.prettify()
print(page)
```

`requests` is the Python canonical package for HTTP calls, and

`request` is a sub-package inside Flask to access HTTP call arguments.